Unable to run sqlcmd via subprocess.Popen
I am trying to run SQL command using SQL file in Python
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=log)
print("command: {}".format(command))
print("split cmd: {}".format(shlex.split(command)))

This is the output on the console
Error occurred while opening or operating on file C: (Reason: Access is denied)

command: sqlcmd  -i C:/Users/MyUser/Git/migrator/__logs__/logs-2024-05-20-105317235524-import/models/.build/scripts/import-Models-EF435017-123D-5CE9-9392-659C88AA2048.sql -S localhost

split cmd:['sqlcmd', '-i', 'C:/Users/MyUser/Git/migrator/__logs__/logs-2024-05-20-104845036741-import/models/.build/scripts/import-Models-EF435017-123D-5CE9-9392-659C88AA2048.sql', '-S', 'localhost'] 


If I add double quotes to the file path and run it manually from the console it will work.
If I remove the prefix C:/Users/MyUser/Git/migrator/ it will also work without needing the double quotes,
(note that this prefix is where im running the python main file.)
Removing the prefix also works with python.

My script also works with Postgres, so if I run my script the same way (using filename) but the command is postgres it also works.
Note: I checked there's no whitespace in the filepath.
Note2: I'm running this script on Windows.
My question is why does not it work with sqlcmd?

Is this specific to sqlcmd or does it also happen for other programs? Care to provide a [mcve]? What system are you running this on? I'm asking that, because it refers to a file named "C:", which is at least odd.

I have a python script that runs a command to execute sql, this scripts is meant to support both postgres and sqlserver. As mentioned above i am using subprocess.Popen to run the command, the problem is the sqlcmd does not seem to work when a sql filepath is in absolute path (hence the "C:") but if running the same command with double quote around the filepath on the console directly it works.
Also if a filepath is relative path it will work on python as well.
This is running on windows.

If I understand you right, you have full control over the called program, so you can intercept and log things like sys.argv and the working directory. This should give you further hints. Further notes: Other differences could be caused by the environment. Also, you say "console" but are you using cmd.exe or Powershell? Those are two different shells that require different syntax. Also, I'm not sure if Popen will use $PATH to locate programs, I'd verify that.
